# Warning Count Magento 2.2 & PHP 7.2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7.2, count

I receive the warning after upgrading to PHP 7.2 while running magento still in 2.2.
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/Select.php on line 71

i tried changing count, but i am stuck.

```
   if (!$this->_isSingleSelection()) {
            $valuesCollection = $option->getOptionValuesByOptionId($value, $this->getProduct()->getStoreId())->load();
            if ($valuesCollection->count() != count($value)) {
                $this->setIsValid(false);
                throw new LocalizedException(__('Please specify product\'s required option(s).'));
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento `2.2` not working with `php 7.2`, you need to upgrade to Magento `2.3.4`

or you can install 2 php versions and change php for magento.

for example for CentOS /RHEL configuration:
https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.
At the moment i only experience this problem, all others have been fixed.

This behaviour only occurs if i try to add a product with radiobutton additions instead of check boxes.
As corona is hitting my business very hard and my hoster will disable php 7.1 at 1st of april i need to find a way around.
updating my shop is to expensiv at the moment as i have a very custom checkout but still need to pay my employees..

I found out i only need to change the way how count() is used but this function is to difficult for me.